# Install MongoDB on CentOs 7 without YUM. have rpm files but not tgz

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos7, rpm

I'm fairly new to Linux and am running CentOS 7. I can do the basics of navigating, creating dirctories, permissions, unzip applications and make SL to the apps but I have no idea what to do with an "rpm" file.

The system that I am trying to install MongoDB 4.2.x on does not have an outside connection. I have the individual rpm files for MongoDB but not the tgz which some article I read said I should use.
There is no way for me to get the tgz over to the machine unless I wait several days.

With only the .rpm files, how do I install MongoDB?

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/][1]

The instructions in the above link say to create the .repo file but that makes a reference to the external URL which the system does not have access to.

```
[mongodb-org-4.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/
```

*

- Again, with only the .rpm files, how do I install MongoDB?

*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need some kind of access to the outside world; you need to get the `rpm` files on your machine...

you can just manually download the `rpm` files you need from https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/RPMS/, copy them to your machine, and then run

```
yum install /path/to/downloaded/mongodb*rpm
```

Comment: Do I run all of the rpm files? Server, shell, tools, mongos?

Comment: that depends on what you need... installing won't do any harm unless eating space...

Comment: There is the main rpm file which to my understanding installs all the other rpms. I have them all within the same directory but I get errors saying they cannot be found as it looks to be looking at root / for the rpm files. How do I configure this to look in the current directory?

Comment: make sure you specify paths: `./mongodb*rpm` and not `mongodb*rpm`. If it doesn't work with `yum` you can do it straight with the `rpm` command: `rpm -ivh ./mongodb*rpm`